# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities error while doing version check

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm executing following linq query in ASP.NET MVC project:

```
Version baseVersion = new Version("1.0.0.0");
var v = (from a in db.table where new Version(a.version) > baseVersion select new { a.id, a.version, a.name}).ToList();
```

While executing this I'm getting this error:

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

When I removed version check and used this query:

```
var v = (from a in db.table select new { a.id, a.version, a.name}).ToList();
```

it executed successfully. How can I make the linq query with version condition to work?

Comment: your link is compiled down to sql code, and sql does not know what a `Version` is, so this will probably not be the way you want to solve this

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig Is there any other way?

Comment: unfortunately I think @Maarten's suggestion is your only way to go. If your version numbers never exceed one decimal (i.e 9.9.9.9 is your max) then you could just use string comparisons and abuse the natural comparison of SQL. `where new a.version > "1.0.0.0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `Version` class to do the comparison, then I see no other option than importing the whole table into memory, and do the comparison there. You can use `IQueryable<T>.AsEnumerable()` for to specify you want to do anything after in memory.

```
Version baseVersion = new Version("1.0.0.0");
var v = db.Table
    .Select(x => new { x.id, x.version, x.name })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => new Version(x.version) > baseVersion)
    .ToList();
```

Note: I've moved the `.Select(...)` to immediately after the `db.Table` to only select the columns you need, which minimizes the memory footprint.

The alternative is that you recreate the `Version` comparison in SQL. But then you are reinventing the wheel.